# Accessing route param when module is lazy loaded

Tags: angular

Routes defined in main module:

```
const mainRoutes = [
{
  path: ':id',
  component: MainComponent,
  canActivate: [ LoadGuard ],
  children: [
    {
     path: 'page',
     loadChildren: () => import('./page/page.module').then((m) => m.PageModule),
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Routes defined in lazy loaded page module:

```
const pageRoutes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: PageComponent,
  children: [
    {
     path: '/hello',
     component: HelloComponent
    }
  ]
}
]
```

LoadGuard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  console.log( route.params['id'] );
  return of(true);
}
```

When go to the route `/my-id/page/hello` the guard above logs `hello` and not `my-id`.

Any idea what this issue is?

Comment: Try accessing router.parent.params

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the forward slash that you have in the beginning of the hello path that is messing with the pattern matching. Try removing it.

`{ path: 'hello', ... }`